# Docker parsing error whilst setting up MediaWiki on RaspberryPi3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, mediawiki

Just for some background, I am setting up mediawiki on a raspberry pi3 for a personal learning project.

I have followed the guide from https://peppe8o.com/personal-mediawiki-with-raspberry-pi-and-docker/ and have been able to follow all but the very last step of running 'docker-compose up -d' and get the error below (I have also pasted the contents of my docker-compose.yml)

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could spot the issue here as I have tried a number of things
(removing and adding spaces in lines 6 & 17 etc....)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mediawiki $ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 3
expected <block end>, but found '-'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 17, column 3
```

Contents of docker-compose.yml:

```
# My MediaWiki
# from peppe8o.com
version: '3'
services:
 mediawiki:
  image: mediawiki
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
   - 8080:80
  links:
   - database
  volumes:
   - mediawiki-www:/var/www/html
 #After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
 #this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
 #the mediawiki service
  - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
 database:
  build: .
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
   - mediawiki-db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
 mediawiki-www:
 mediawiki-db:
```

Kind regards

Layerz

Comment: mmmhh... Docker and persistance (db) is not a good mix...

Comment: Try "cat -A docker-compose.yml" to check for invisible char